# help htaccess isapi rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, isapi-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^olddomain.php?cat=39$ http://www.newdomain.com/firstdir/seconddir/? [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^olddomain.php\?cat\=39$ http://www.newdomain.com/firstdir/seconddir/? [R=301,NC] 
RewriteRule ^olddomain.php?cat\=39$ http://www.newdomain.com/firstdir/seconddir/? [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^olddomain.php\?cat=39$ http://www.newdomain.com/firstdir/seconddir/? [R=301,NC]
```

why they work??? the issue i think has something to do with the first question mark, the first equal sign, or the digits '39'...haha

Comment: I'm in idiot... I'm so sorry. My question why do NONE of them work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember RewriteRule matches only your URI and it will never match the host name or query string. Here is the right way to do what you are trying to do:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^olddomain\.php$ http://www.newdomain.com/firstdir/seconddir/? [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Comment: oh ok. that sucks but at least now i understand. thank you very much